# Removing cells zero for a gene from a scRNA-seq data

Tags: r, scrnaseq, 10x-genomics

I have a big single-cell RNA seq data

```
> dput(head(new.dat[,1:10]))
structure(list(cell1 = c(0.793763840992639, 0, 1.96843530982957, 
0.461736429639991, 0.717968540649498, 0), cell2 = c(3.61741696702738, 
0.231662370550224, 0, 0, 0, 0), cell3 = c(4.14348883366621, 0.118161316317251, 
0.08074552209482, 2.27968429766934, 0.0470313356296409, 0), cell4 = c(1.34783143327084, 
0.0094666040612932, 1.14392942941128, 0.652535826921119, 0.357542816432864, 
0.149587369334621), cell5 = c(1.27104023273899, 1.55185229643731, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0117525723115277), cell6 = c(1.92307653575663, 0, 
0, 0.319156642478379, 0, 0), cell7 = c(3.9343015424917, 0.132824589520901, 
0.119679885703561, 0.772516422897241, 0.0236884909844904, 0), 
    cell8 = c(3.74969491678643, 0.103404975609384, 0.0354753982873036, 
    0, 0, 0), cell9 = c(1.19084857532713, 3.9213265721495, 0, 
    0.0341973245272891, 0.0419122921627454, 0), cell10 = c(4.1224255501566, 
    0.301871669274068, 0.0633536200981225, 0.389959552469879, 
    0, 0.0405296102106492)), row.names = c("PTPRC", "MHC-II", 
"ITGAM", "Ly6C", "Ly6G", "EMR1"), class = "data.frame")
> 

> dim(new.dat)
[1]     33 263086
>
```

How I `remove every columns` which are `zero` for one gene, let's say `PTPRC`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
WhichCells(seurat_object made by this matrix, slot = 'counts', expression = PTPRC > 0 )
```

By Seurat R package this is possible

Comment: Please accept one answer if either of them solved your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hi there, it would be nice to write more details and an actual working code.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic R subsetting operation. Most subset operations give you a subset of rows based on a column, while you're doing the opposite here - but the logic is the same.

This gives you a subset of rows when the expression is based on a column

```
df[logical_expression_that_subsets_rows,]
```

Why not try this - it should give you a subset of columns based on a row value. (Untested, but you should be able to build on this):

```
df[, logical_expression_that_subsets_columns]
```

The logical expression for the first could be `df$cell1 < 0.5` (or the equivalent `df[,"cell1"] < 0.5`. You should be able to get a logical expression for the second based on this.